# flutter path_provider could not read downloaded files

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using path_provider on flutter and would like to build Download file(mp4&jpg, from aws S3) and play it. I succeeded download and confirmed file is downloaded.(on ios)

But, when access the files using path_provider, raised error like below.

```
Unable to load asset: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B78BC67E-B127-4DD0-8A42-965EE645157B/data/Containers
```

the saving  method is below

```
 Future<File> _getFile(String filename) async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${dir.path}/$filename");
  }
```

```
final file = await _getFile("filename");
file.writeAsBytes(Bytes);
```

and the load method is below

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
.
.
.
Image(image: AssetImage('${directory.path}/filename')) // /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B78BC67E-B127-4DD0-8A42-965EE645157B/data/Containers/Data/Application/46EF23F5-840C-47D4-8314-B97CDEE2198C/Documents
.
.
.
```

Comment: Think you need to use FileImage, not Asset Image.

Comment: Thanks a comment and you save my lot of time! I should read document carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I need to use FileImage instead of Asset.
Thanks for [GrahamD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10376604/grahamd)